# Chrome adds extra styles when copy html to clipboard

Tags: google-chrome, clipboard

When I copy formatted text (bold, underline etc.) from any website to Gmail message, Chrome add extra stuff (SPAN and a lot of extra styles). Why? In Firefox RAW HTML is copied - no extra data. How to copy selected HTML as is in Chrome (like Firefox)?